# Extract lat/long coordinates from a php string

Tags: php, string, extract

I need to extract latitude and longitude coordinates from a string using php. The string will always be formatted as such:

```
"(42.32783298989135, -70.99989162915041)"
```

However the length of each value will vary from use to use. What's the best way to extract the values? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use sscanf to do this:

```
sscanf($string, '"(%f, %f)"', $lat, $lng);
```

Test:

```
php > sscanf('"(42.32783298989135, -70.99989162915041)"', '"(%f, %f)"', $lat, $lng);
php > var_dump($lat, $lng);
float(42.327832989891)
float(-70.99989162915)
```

Comment: Neat solution, but note that there will be some loss of precision involved.

Comment: @mfonda: Could you elaborate? Do you mean that precision could be lost if there were more digits?

Comment: @greg0ire: Look at your above output for example: the original input has the latitude of "42.32783298989135", but using float leaves you with just "42.327832989891" (missing the last 3 digits, which depending on the application may be important). For more information, see http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: @mfonda - 42.32783298989135, -70.99989162915041 has a latitude error of 1.111 nanometers, longitude error of 0.824 nanometers (uncertainty 1.383 nanometers); 42.327832989891, 70.99989162915 has a latitude error of 111.080 nanometers, longitude error of 82.424 nanometers (uncertainty 138.320 nanometers)... yes, I do mean nanometers... that margin of rounding error should be accurate enough for most purposes.

Comment: @mfonda: oh yeah, I compared the original input with what was in the question, I must be very tired... but I think that this loss of precision is not significant (< 1 mm)
EDIT: @Mark Baker: Wow! Thanks for the math!

Comment: @Mark Baker: My point is one should always proceed with caution when using floats, and be aware that rounding error will occur, and take the time to decide whether or not it will be an issue in any given situation.

Comment: @mfonda - while there will inevitably be a degree of error when working with floats, var_dump isn't a particularly good measure of this, as it will use PHP's precision setting when casting to string for the var_dump display; and the last three digits (in the quoted example) are lost because of the cast to string rather than the precision of the float in PHP. Set the precision to 16, and those missing digits will be displayed correctly when casting the float to string, even on a 32-bit system.

Comment: uhm, everyone seems to forget that latitude and longitude also must be within the range of respectively -90,+90 and -180, +180

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to extract the numbers from the brackets and then use the `explode` command to split the numbers into an array.

Your regex would be something like

```
/(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+, -?[0-9]+.[0-9]+)/
```

and your delimiter for the explode command would be a comma.

Comment: Avoid using regexp when you can.

Comment: Commonly repeated mantra: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$withoutParentheses = substr($string, 1, -1);
$coordinates = explode(', ', $coordinates);
$longitude = floatval($coordinates[0]);
$latitude = floatval($coordinates[1]);
```

Comment: Instead of `substr` you can also use `trim`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with on my own:

```
function LatFromString($mCenterString){
    //(42.32783298989135, -70.99989162915041)
    $mLatLong = explode(",", $mCenterString);
    $mLat = '';
    if(count($mLatLong) == 2){
        $mLat = substr($mLatLong[0], 1);
    }
    return $mLat;
}
function LongFromString($mCenterString){
    //(42.32783298989135, -70.99989162915041)
    $mLatLong = explode(",", $mCenterString);
    $mLat = '';
    if(count($mLatLong) == 2){
        $mLong = substr($mLatLong[1], 0, -1);
    }
    return $mLong;
}
```

How does this look?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
            $str = "(42.32783298989135, -70.99989162915041)";

            function extractlatlong($str){
                $latlong = explode(",",$str);

                if(count($latlong) == 2){
                    $lat = preg_replace("%[^0-9.]%","",$latlong[0]);
                    $long = preg_replace("%[^0-9.]%","",$latlong[1]);
                    return array("lat"=>$lat,"long"=>$long);
                } else {
                    return NULL;
                }
            }

            print_r(extractlatlong($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `sscanf()` (and I probably would), but don't want to lose any precision from casting the numeric values as floats, then use a couple of negated character classes.  You don't' have to match the trailing `)` to extract what you need.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/daAqb))

```
$latlon = "(42.32783298989135, -70.99989162915041)";
sscanf($latlon, '(%[^,], %[^)]', $lat, $lon);
var_export([$lat, $lon]);
```

Output as an array of strings:

```
array (
  0 => '42.32783298989135',
  1 => '-70.99989162915041',
)
```

Or if you just want an indexed array of the two values like the above output:

```
var_export(sscanf($latlon, '(%[^,], %[^)]'));
```